# How to format String to use Today and Yesterday instead of Date if appropriate in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, date, calendar

**Context**

I have a custom `Stringify Method` on `Date` formatting a given `Date` into a `String`.
The result looks like this:

> `October 17th, 2022 at 1:27pm`

However, when the `Date` is `Today`, `Yesterday` or `Tomorrow`, I would like to replace the actual `Date` with this specific `String` description. The result should look like this:

> `Today at 1:27pm`

---

**Code**

```swift
extension Date {
    func stringify() -> String {
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        
        dateFormatter.dateStyle = .long
        dateFormatter.timeStyle = .short
        
        return dateFormatter.string(from: self)
    }
}
```

---

**Question**

- How can I achieve this behaviour, since `DateFormatter` is not supporting it?

Comment: RelativeDateTimeFormatter ?

Comment: @Larme As far as I know `RelativeDateTimeFormatter` only shows the relative passed `Time` from now, like `5 Minutes Ago`. However, I would like to achieve a different behaviour including the `Time` always and just adjusting the `Day Format` if appropriate.

Comment: @christophriepe I think you still want `RelativeDateTimeFormatter`, just with its [`dateTimeStyle`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/relativedatetimeformatter/3130995-datetimestyle) set to [`.named`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/relativedatetimeformatter/datetimestyle). If you only want that named style for certain days, and have a sort of hybrid approach, you might need to implement that switching yourself, I'm not sure

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As suggested in the comments, you can use `DateFormatter` for this, the trick is to turn on the `doesRelativeDateFormatting` [flag](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsdateformatter/1415848-doesrelativedateformatting).

```
let today = Date()
let yesterday = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: -1, to: today)!
let tomorrow = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: 1, to: today)!

let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateStyle = .long
dateFormatter.timeStyle = .short
dateFormatter.doesRelativeDateFormatting = true

let todayString = dateFormatter.string(from: today)
print(todayString) // Today at 20:44

let yesterdayString = dateFormatter.string(from: yesterday)
print(yesterdayString) // Yesterday at 20:44

let tomorrowString = dateFormatter.string(from: tomorrow)
print(tomorrowString) // Tomorrow at 20:44
```

Comment: Thank you for the simple and perfectly working solution!